# How to test data usage of a single chrome window

Tags: automated-testing

I am trying to find an application to test the data usage of a WEBrtc based application.

The goal is to determine how much data is used during a 10 minute video call.

Any help would be appreciated as google has been nothing but a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to know how much data is transferred during the call.

For this purpose, I'd probably go for the following set of tools.

- wireshark, tcpdump or other tool for capturing network traffic
- [capinfos](https://linux.die.net/man/1/capinfos) tool that is part of wireshark-cli (e.g. https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/wireshark-cli/) tool set

I can imagine the following scenario:

- turning off (near) everything on the computer that communicates over the wire
- starting wireshark/tcpdump and saving it all into a file (like `$ tcpdump -w file`)
- after the call finishes, just stop capturing the network traffic
- using capinfos: `$ capinfos file`:

```
$ capinfos file 
File name:           file
File type:           Wireshark/tcpdump/... - pcap
File encapsulation:  Ethernet
File timestamp precision:  microseconds (6)
Packet size limit:   file hdr: 262144 bytes
Number of packets:   91 k
File size:           94 MB
Data size:           92 MB
Capture duration:    95.737354 seconds
First packet time:   2020-01-29 20:49:45.777379
Last packet time:    2020-01-29 20:51:21.514733
Data byte rate:      967 kBps
Data bit rate:       7,738 kbps
Average packet size: 1007.70 bytes
Average packet rate: 959 packets/s
SHA256:              8aeb915d396756155bd2a372ee2ef1cb997561f0e58f6662f60cd632dc517dfa
RIPEMD160:           4a3e6bd4e996512787ce63acd9fa3b11ae7aa2db
SHA1:                be025b1cc0ac6f90a3179d76c97ea6bc199407c6
Strict time order:   True
Number of interfaces in file: 1
Interface #0 info:
                     Encapsulation = Ethernet (1 - ether)
                     Capture length = 262144
                     Time precision = microseconds (6)
                     Time ticks per second = 1000000
                     Number of stat entries = 0
                     Number of packets = 91904
```

The **Data size** (`$ capinfos -d file`) field is what you're looking for.

The downside of this is obvious: if you have other traffic on your machine, it will be included in the data size. You might, however, use some filters, so you actually capture just desired traffic. That'd be one way how you can make the approximation more accurate. So it depends a bit on how accurate you want the result to be(?)